# Upper bound on Lipschitz continuous hessian

Tags: functions, inequality, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Lipschitz continuous hessian for the twice differentiable function $f$ is defined as, for any $x, y$,

$$\|\nabla^2 f(x) - \nabla^2 f(y)\| \leq M\|x-y\|$$ for some postive $M$, how to derive the upper bound of

$|f(y) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) - \frac{1}{2}(y - x) \nabla^2 f(x)^T (y-x)| \leq \frac{M}{6}\|y-x\|^3$

Comment: This is Lemma 1.2.4 in: Yu. Nesterov, Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization - A basic course, Kluwer Ac. Publishers, 2004.

Comment: @Pantelis Sopasakis, I saw this lemma from the book, but the proof is omitted. I have a hard time to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
We will here denote the inner product of $x$ and $y$ by $\langle x, y\rangle.
Since $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, we may use the fact that

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y) = f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle + \tfrac{1}{2} \langle \nabla^2 f(x+\lambda (y-x))(y-x), y-x \rangle
\end{aligned}\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

for some $\lambda\in [0,1]$. We may write this equivalently as (and this is maybe more convenient)

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y) = f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle + \int_0^1 \int_0^\tau \left\langle \nabla^2 f(x+\alpha (y-x))(y-x), y-x\right\rangle \d \alpha\ \d \tau.
\end{aligned}\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Since $\nabla^2 f$ is $M$-Lipschitz,

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\|\nabla^2 f(x+\alpha(y-x)) - \nabla^2 f(x)\| \leq M\alpha \|x-y\|, \\
\Leftrightarrow& \nabla^2 f(x+\alpha(y-x)) = \nabla^2 f(x) + H,
\end{aligned}\tag{3}
$$

where $\|H\|\leq M\alpha \|x-y\|$. We may now easily plug (3) into (2) and prove the original inequality. In particular, because of \eqref{2}:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y) &= f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle + \int_0^1 \int_0^\tau \left\langle \nabla f^2(x)(y-x), y-x\right\rangle \d \alpha\ \d \tau\\
&+ \int_0^1 \int_0^\tau \left\langle H(y-x), y-x\right\rangle \d \alpha\ \d \tau,
\end{aligned}\tag{4}\label{4}
$$

where the first integral in \eqref{4} is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \int_0^\tau \left\langle \nabla f^2(x)(y-x), y-x\right\rangle \d \alpha\ \d \tau = \tfrac{1}{2}\left\langle \nabla f^2(x)(y-x), y-x\right\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

and the second integral's absolute value is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_0^1 \int_0^\tau \left\langle H(y-x), y-x\right\rangle \d \alpha\ \d \tau\right| &\leq \int_0^1 \int_0^\tau \|H\|\cdot \|y-x\|^2 \d \alpha\ \d \tau\\
&\leq \int_0^1 \int_0^\tau M \alpha \|y-x\|^3 \d \alpha\ \d \tau\\
&=\tfrac{M}{6}\|y-x\|^3.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: thanks for your solution. It is a rigid proof except (2). i.e., if we do integration on $\int_0^\tau \left\langle \nabla f^2(x+\alpha (y-x))(y-x), y-x\right\rangle \d \alpha$, it equals to $\langle \nabla f(x+\tau (y-x)) - \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle$ instead of (1). In this case, $\alpha$ is misused. It is a fixed variable in (1), while a design variable in (2).

Comment: @ZhuanghuaLiu Equation (2) is from Nesterov's book: See the second equation in the proof of Theorem 2.1.4, page 55. By the way, I haven't used (1) anywhere in the proof. I'll change $\alpha$ in (1) into $\lambda$ to avoid confusion. I noticed also that I accidentally wrote "because of (1)", instead of "because of (2)" - I have now corrected it.

Comment: I see, the integration is the same as $f(y) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle$, perfect! Thanks for this approach.